# How to prevent iframe affecting browser history

Tags: javascript, html

I'm encountering a browser history issue when working on a web project.

Theres an iframe in my page, which I would change its `src` value using Javascript.
The whole thing works just fine except this change of src would affect the browser history.

I do not want to push the browser history, when I change the iframe url.
I'm expecting that the user would leave the whole base page and go to the previous location when clicking on the back button, rather than just going back on the changed iframe.

What I've tried:

- remove the former iframe, and replace with a new one having the new `src` value
- use `replaceWith()` method from jQuery
- use `iframe.contentWindow.location.replace()` to replace the iframe location

Both methods above behaved nothing different than just changing the `src` directly on my Safari browser. The back button is still affected.

Haven't tested yet on other browsers, but I assume other webkit browsers would be the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305069/can-you-use-hash-navigation-without-affecting-history

Comment: Yes, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951691/back-button-inside-a-iframe-using-history-js

Comment: @BharathR tried `replace` already. And using `replaceHistory` gives me a `SecurityError`

Comment: @roywasse I'm not trying to go back on that iframe. I'm trying to eliminate it's effect on the browser history.

Comment: @roywasse I'm asking for the reverse of the link you suggested.

Comment: Just to make certain for the first method you listed, are you setting the src on your new iframe before you attach it to the DOM?

Comment: Also, are you building it programatically with createElement, appendChild, etc, or through some other means like innerHTML?

Comment: @Brandon Yes, I changed src before inserting to DOM. I've tried both appendChild and innerHTML, which made no difference to me, the history is still touched.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue with using jsPDF and an iframe to show live PDF updates as the user edits. I guess I will put an extra back button on the page for now. The other comment links don't seem to be what I need.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is something else in your code that we're not seeing, because .contentWindow.location.replace works in my testing.

https://codepen.io/tmdesigned/pen/WJEqON

I also tried that on a blank html page outside of codePen, thinking the codepen editor was affecting the outcome. It continued to work.

I've pasted it as a snippet below for the code, although I don't think SO allows iFrames to work.

```js
$( 'html' ).on( 'click', '.change-iframe', function() {
    $( '#dynamic-iframe' )[0].contentWindow.location.replace( $( this ).data( 'src' ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="dynamic-iframe" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XlqoPpLMdwY" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe> 

<div>
    <button class="change-iframe" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0RIrdFfy9t4">Another</button>
    <button class="change-iframe" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QMQbAoTLJX8">Another</button>
    <button class="change-iframe" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wppBd-52LT0">Another</button>
</div>
```